# C# HttpWebRequest to Scorm Cloud always returning error 400 bad request

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, tin-can-api

I am trying to post Tin Can Statements to a Scorm Cloud LRS via c# HttpWebRequest in JSON format. However I always get error 400. The authentication is correct so what is wrong with the JSON? I have tried encoding as UTF8 also and still no dice

Here is the code and credentials needed:

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://cloud.scorm.com/ScormEngineInterface/TCAPI/RCFZ5D8GXU/sandbox/");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    String autorization= "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("RCFZ5D8GXU222" + ":" + "YQA3VfX1NiuYkKXEEzkKu723NwejpwNkB6x0Vhg3"));

    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", autorization);
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Experience-API-Version", "1.0.1");
    string jsonText = "{"+
                        "   \"actor\": {"+
                            "   \"mbox\": \"mailto:Steeno@gmail.com\","+
                            "   \"name\": \"Austin Glatt\","+
                            "   \"objectType\": \"Agent\""+
                            "},"+
                            "\"verb\": {"+
                            "   \"id\": \"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/attempted\","+
                            "   \"display\": {"+
                            "       \"en-US\": \"attempted\""+
                            "   }"+
                            "},"+
                            "\"object\": {"+
                            "   \"id\": \"http://www.example.com/tincan/activities/cMjKwAGI\","+
                            "   \"objectType\": \"Activity\","+
                            "   \"definition\": {"+
                            "       \"name\": {"+
                            "           \"en-US\": \"Part Removal\""+
                            "       },"+
                            "       \"description\": {"+
                            "           \"en-US\": \"On Engine 155\""+
                            "       }"+
                            "   }"+
                            "}"+
                        "}";
    byte [] jsonData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonText);
    Debug.Log(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonData));
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
    using (var streamWriter = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        streamWriter.Write(jsonData,0,jsonData.Length);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }


     try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.Log("POST result"+result);
            }
    }
    catch(WebException ex)
    {

        if (ex.Response != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
            foreach(DictionaryEntry d in ex.Data)
                Debug.Log(d.ToString());

                 string errorDetail = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream(), true))
                {
                    errorDetail = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Debug.Log(errorDetail);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The body of the response should tell you the reason the LRS is returning a 400 status code. If you add that to your question we can be more precise with an answer.

Comment: Also you shouldn't post auth credentials in SO.

Comment: I mentioned it below, but the 400 status code is due to malformed url. The URL in the code is correct (statement generator hits it just fine), so it has to be the JSON I feel. As for the credentials this LRS is throw-away and will cease to exist once I get this settled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the "statements" on the URL, your request should be going to:

https://cloud.scorm.com/ScormEngineInterface/TCAPI/RCFZ5D8GXU/sandbox/statements

Original answer in case anyone cares:

It appears you are posting a 0.95 or 1.0.x statement, but you don't seem to be setting an X-Experience-API-Version header, so the LRS is probably interpreting it as a 0.9 statement which would be invalid.

I'd highly recommend using a library to build the requests along with the content of the request. We have one available here:

http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCan.NET/

Comment: Mr. Miller just the man I was hoping to get in touch with! I did try adding the header with version 1.0.1 (I actually used your GIT project to see what you guys did and to look for discrepancies, still no luck. I can't use the library because I am integrating with Unity and want it to work for web player also (web player demands no  .NET libraries can be used for security reasons). Also your library relies on a JSON library which contains .cs files of the same name so even if i drop the source directly in my Unity project the compiler complains about multiple scripts with same name.

Comment: Just FYI I updated the code to reflect the most current attempt. I am still getting the error 400 (malformed URL being the culprit). It seems it still doesnt like my JSON even with latest XAPI header string set. I used the statement generator from the tin can site and just wrapped it in string form.

Comment: See updated answer. Have to specify the endpoint on the base LRS URL.